# Bot fails to deploy with 500 server error

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I am trying to build multiple deployment environments for web bot in Node.js. I created 2 resource groups and generated all the necessary credentials - app id, app password and secret key (direct line). I am using bitbucket pipelines for the deployment and variables match for each branch.

The end result is that one bot is working and the other returns 500 error. In Kudu I can see that the code is running. When I try to run code manually from CMD it returns an error:

> bot.listen() is not a function

This is confusing, as the only thing that is different between the 2 bots are credentials - app id, app password and secret key for the direct line. I double checked whether values are pasted correctly. Still nothing. Does this seem like an issue with the values of these variables?

In addition, the one that is working was set up in August, while the other one was created a couple of days ago. In the setup procedure, it was noticed that registration is required to get the app password (which was not the case with the first one).

Also, `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword` are missing in the Application Settings for the newly created bot. Has anything changed in the process of creation of the bot?

Comment: When you say 'creation of the bot', do you mean creating the bot on Azure? Because in August, the bot framework was using V3, and now they've released V4. Some setting aren't the same, no.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I created a new bot on Azure. Can you please tell me or share some link where I can see the new settings?

Comment: What happens if you set the `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword` to what you are using in the bot itself? (You mentioned having those saved somewhere?) Those two keys are [autogenerated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#create-a-new-bot-service-1) during the creation process, otherwise it'll just take whatever you entered into the fields.

Comment: So the way pass is generated is as described in [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). We used Id and Pass in our repo as env variable, so we are able to create connector to the bot. These credential do not work for us. 

In addition, in the previous bots we build, in the application settings we clearly see MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword. Now, we can't see these variables. I tried to put them there manually, but that did not get us to the results we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The `microsoftAppId` is as listed on the `settings` blade, but to generate a password make sure to follow [this section of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#bot-channels-registration-password):

> From the Settings blade, click Manage. This is the link appearing by
>   the Microsoft App ID. This link will open a window where you can
>   generate a new password.  Manage link in Settings blade
>
> Click Generate New Password. This will generate a new password for
>   your bot. Copy this password and save it to a file. This is the only
>   time you will see this password. If you do not have the full password
>   saved, you will need to repeat the process to create a new password
>   should you need it later.

and set that up in your bot in the `.bot` file, rather than in the `.env` file

An example `.bot` file, if you do not have one looks like this:
filename: `botName.bot`

```
{
"name": "transcriptloggerBot",
"services": [
    {
        "type": "endpoint",
        "name": "development",
        "endpoint": "<host>/api/messages",
        "appId": "<MSappId>",
        "appPassword": "<MSappPassword>",
        "id": "1"
    }
],
"padlock": "",
"version": "2.0"
}
```